# Django 2 migrate error

Tags: django-2.0

### I have problem with Django 2, the command was working fine but after that I got this Error:

python manage.py migrate

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "manage.py", line 15, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "/Users/nawaf/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

File "/Users/nawaf/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()

File "/Users/nawaf/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

File "/Users/nawaf/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()

File "/Users/nawaf/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)

File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import

File "", line 983, in _find_and_load

File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked

File "", line 728, in exec_module

File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

File "/Users/nawaf/Desktop/python/blog/models.py", line 5, in 
    class Post(models.Model):

File "/Users/nawaf/Desktop/python/blog/models.py", line 10, in Post
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(defult=timezone.now)

File "/Users/nawaf/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 1163, in **init**
    super().**init**(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'defult'

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your `models.py` file. Should be:

```
...
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

rather than `defult=timezone.now`